# Customizing tooltip on Google Timeline Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I created a Google Timeline Chart to see my musical listening history. It looks like this:

[image]

I want to remove duration part from the tooltip, but couldn't find any option for it. I tried adding these lines:

```
dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', role:'tooltip'});
```

and a row in my `dataTable.addRows([])` function looks like this:

```
['25 August', 'Kasabian - La Fee Verte', new Date(2016,01,01, 13,37,32), new Date(2016,01,01, 13,43,19), 'tooltip example'],
```

but it still shows the same tooltip as in the image. I actually want to show `Kasabian - La Fee Verte and 25 August: 1:37 pm - 1:43 pm` just like in the image, but I want to remove duration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

according to the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#data-format) for a Timeline chart, the tooltip should be in the 3rd column.

see following, working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'RowLabel'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'string', id: 'BarLabel'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'Start'});
    dataTable.addColumn({type: 'date', id: 'End'});

    dataTable.addRows([
      ['25 August', 'Kasabian - La Fee Verte', new Date(2016,01,01, 13,37,32), new Date(2016,01,01, 13,43,19)],
      ['26 August', 'Test Data 1', new Date(2016,01,01, 13,37,32), new Date(2016,01,01, 13,43,19)],
      ['27 August', 'Test Data 2', new Date(2016,01,01, 13,37,32), new Date(2016,01,01, 13,43,19)],
    ]);

    dataTable.insertColumn(2, {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}});

    var dateFormat = new google.visualization.DateFormat({
      pattern: 'h:mm a'
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < dataTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      var tooltip = '<div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>' +
        dataTable.getValue(i, 1) + '</span></div><div class="ggl-tooltip"><span>' +
        dataTable.getValue(i, 0) + '</span>: ' +
        dateFormat.formatValue(dataTable.getValue(i, 3)) + ' - ' +
        dateFormat.formatValue(dataTable.getValue(i, 4)) + '</div>';

      dataTable.setValue(i, 2, tooltip);
    }

    chart.draw(dataTable, {
      tooltip: {
        isHtml: true
      }
    });
  },
  packages: ['timeline']
});
```

```css
.ggl-tooltip {
  border: 1px solid #E0E0E0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica;
  padding: 6px 6px 6px 6px;
}

.ggl-tooltip span {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: it indeed helped, thanks. I didn't know it had to be in the 2nd column, that was the problem but also thanks for the styling!