# Google Visualization Datatable: DateFormatter is not working

Tags: google-visualization, timeline

I'm trying to show 12 hours format on Google Chart timeline.

This is the example from Google with arrayToDataTable method. It is working fine and this is the result I really want in 12hrs format with am & pm.

`Code Pen link 1`: http://codepen.io/Thein/pen/mAOrow

This is how I populated dataTable using `google.visualization.DataTable()`. 
Additionally, I formatted -

```
var formatter_12h = new google.visualization.DateFormat({ pattern: "d/MM/yy h:m:s aa" });
formatter_12h.format(dataTable, 1);
formatter_12h.format(dataTable, 2);
```

It always comes up with 24 hours format in tooltip.

`Code Pen link 2`: http://codepen.io/Thein/pen/KgNvJA

I tried to play with Culture value in  in web.config as follow but it is still showing 24h format.

```
<globalization enableClientBasedCulture="false" uiCulture="en-AU" culture="en-AU" />
```

> EDIT: It seems that Snippet 2 code is working with 12 hours format on
>   Apahache server and It is showing 24 hours format on IIS server.

Comment: you can provide custom tooltip to control exact content -- [here is an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38306489/5090771) that builds the tooltip dynamically from the data, and uses the `formatValue` method on `DateFormat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to WhiteHat and his solution. I have fixed the Timeline chart as follow:

`Code Pen link 3`: http://codepen.io/Thein/pen/LRbdKv

HhAxis is quite messy though. It is so much cleaner in Code Pen link 1(http://codepen.io/Thein/pen/mAOrow). Please post your answer if you can get the result exactly like Code Pen link 1 with dataTable, I will accept your answer.