# Assign a role/customize HTML tooltip to PieChart/DonutChart Google Charts VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-visualization, data-visualization, pie-chart

I've implemented a VueJS wrapper for Google Charts called [vue-google-charts](https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts) and I'm looking to solve a tool tip scenario.

I'm looking to customize a `PieChart` tooltip by leveraging `toolip: {isHtml: true}` which is set here in this options directive, `:options="chartDonutOptions"`.

The data looks as such:

```
chartDonutData: [
['Stage', 'Percent', 'Tooltip'],
['Data 1, null, ''],
['Data 2, null, ''],
['Data 3, null, ''],
['Data 4, null, ''],
['Data 5, null, '']
]
```

Note the empty strings on position 2 after `null`. When I make an API call to update this object, I assign values to both the `null` and empty `string` positions. However, when I update string values into those areas, I cannot get them to display when I interact with each slice of the pie.

Only position 0 and 1 of the array displays:
**Data 1**
**15.743 (15.7%)**

I expect position 0, 1 and 2 of each row to display:
**Data 1**
**15.743 (15.7%)**
**My updated string here!**

In my searches, a lot of comments suggest on assigning a role to the column.

I'm curious on how you set that with respect to [VueJS/vue-google-charts](https://github.com/devstark-com/vue-google-charts). Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing the tooltip column heading to an object.

```
['Stage', 'Percent', {type: 'string', role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}],
```

Comment: This partially works but only the updated string displays in the respective tooltip when interacting with a pie slice. However, this suggestion is headed in the right direction.

Comment: not sure I understand. what part about this isn't working?

Comment: I need "Data 1 15.743 (15.7%) My updated string here!" this to display but only get this "My updated string here!" displaying in the tooltip.

Comment: sounds like maybe you are trying to append custom info to the default tooltip. but that's not how it works. if you supply a value in the tooltip column, then only that value is displayed. and the default tooltip is removed. you will need to supply everything you want to be displayed...

Comment: That makes sense. I'd essentially be capturing all those values I need and pumping it into that very object from your solution, yes? And since it's an HTML display, I can style accordingly.

Comment: you wouldn't actually change the object in the header, you would just supply the entire html string as the value of the tooltip column on each row. [here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38306489/5090771)