# Google charts Timeline change time language

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization, timeline

I need change timeline period to another language.
I used this code to translate:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['timeline'], 'language': 'pt'});
```

The label "Duration" to 'pt' "Duração" is translated, but the time period "seconds" is in english. 
How I can change the time period "seconds" to 'pt' ?

[image]

Comment: if the language option doesn't work, then you can provide you own custom tooltip. see the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline#data-format) for a timeline chart, column 2.

Comment: Have some exemple of this?

Comment: see this answer --> [Customizing tooltip on Google Timeline Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38306489/5090771)